# svn access to a repository in a user's home directory

Tags: linux, svn

I have a personal project which is stored in an svn repository in my home directory on a server. I want to give another user access to the repository.

I have given the user read permissions on my home directory (but not any of the documents or subfolders). I have also given them read and execute permissions on the repository.

When I attempt to checkout the repository locally as the user with:

```
 svn co file:///home/myusername/theRepository ./aName
```

I get the message

svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///home/myusername/theRepository'
svn: Can't open file '/home/myusername/theRepository/format': Permission denied

Changing the permissions on format has no effect (e.g. giving group, user, and world all read/write/exec permissions still produces exactly this message).

I'm sure there must be a way to do this. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I would like to allow users to access it using svn+ssh.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Giving the new user read access to all higher level directories resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should not give the other user *file* permissions on your account. You should configure your SVN repository (typically, it will have a conf directory with passwd and authz files) to create an *SVN* account for the other user and set appropriate permissions for that account on the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to go to the /conf/ directory in your svn directory and update the passwd file to allow for another user?

You should be able to open up passwd with VIM (assuming this is a Linux box) and add the new user for the repo. Format of the new user in the file is like  = ...

i.e. 
John Doe = password123

Save the file and restart the SVN service.